# Installing Docker-Compose Python Module Using Ansible

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, pip, ansible

I am using Ansible to automate the deployment of my homelab, which is mostly run through docker compose stacks. I have a parent `deploy-docker-compose` role, which installs docker and, using Ansible's `ansible.builtin.pip` module, installs the docker-compose SDK, which the community docker-compose modules for Ansible depend on.

System-wide python package installation has been [heavily discouraged by PEP 668.](https://peps.python.org/pep-0668/) Now, when I try to run the Ansible Pip module, it errors out with `error: externally-managed environment`, saying I can override this with `--break-system-packages`. Obviously, I'm not too keen on that solution, since I seem to be running the risk of breaking system packages which rely on Python modules, and it seems a bit of a hack.

So what *is* the solution to this? Can Ansible's Pip module set up a virtual environment in such a way as downstream tasks can make use of the Docker-Compose Python module? Would I need to have every task depend on the Docker-Compose role? Can I install a parallel python distribution to the system (Ubuntu) packaged Python, and use that for my Ansible commands?